# Create large table by joining multiple tables together

Tags: sql

For the following set of tables I would like to create a large table to execute queries on using inner joins - how would I go about this? I want to join the tables `tweet_hashtag, tweet, hashtag_fc` and `game` to form a larger table that I can query.

`tweet_hashtag` is a lookup table to relate the `tweet` and `hashtag_fc` tables using the tweet_id and hashtag_fc.

In the `hashtag_fc` table `fc_id` is a foreign key to the `game` table but it is keyed twice in the sense that `fc1` and `fc2` are linked to the `fc_id` in the `hashtag_fc` table.

```
Game table
+----+-----+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| id | fc1 | fc2 | officialstart         | officialend           | halftimestart         | halftimeend           |
+----+-----+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| 25 | 4   | 6   | 2017-11-29 19:45:00.0 | 2017-11-29 21:30:00.0 | 2017-11-29 20:30:00.0 | 2017-11-29 20:45:00.0 |
+----+-----+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+

hashtag_fc table

+------------+-------+
| hashtag_id | fc_id |
+------------+-------+
| 7          | 7     |
+------------+-------+

tweet table

+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| tweet_id           | created               | user_id   |
+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| 934425435399704584 | 2017-11-25 14:15:59.0 | 364263622 |
+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------+

tweet hashtag table

+--------------------+------------+
| tweet_id           | hashtag_id |
+--------------------+------------+
| 935948744515874816 | 12         |
+--------------------+------------+
```

Comment: How do your foreign keys map out? There doesn't appear to be any correlation between the tables.

Comment: Shall I explain in the question?

Comment: Please add the foreign keys. Otherwise w'll be just guessing.

Comment: The question is clear; it's just difficult to tell which numbers map together as foreign keys. Like how can you tell that a particular tweet is about a particular game? Surely you need something like a `game_id` column in your `tweet` table. Or is that what the `hashtag_id` column represents in the `tweet hashtag` table?

Comment: Hi, I have added the relations in for you - I hope that these make sense

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. That is if I understood your example correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM Game g
JOIN hashtag_fc ht ON g.fc1 = ht.fc_id
    OR g.fc2 = ht.fc_id
JOIN tweet_hashtag tht ON ht.hashtag_id = tht.hashtag_id
JOIN tweet t ON tht.tweet_id = t.tweet_id
```